# How to create a python virtual restricted environment with limit of tools use

Tags: python, virtualenv, development-environment

My question will be hard to understand, but I will try.

I would like to create a programming environment in one of my applications, in a way that enables user to program in a limited way, so that it cannot execute commands that I prevent, for example: I want to prevent file creation, how do I prevent that while still being able to program with Python? All this must be done in an external environment.

Let me rephrase the question,
I want to create a software virtual environment that enables the user to program in this environment in a limited way, as I want to prevent the programmer from using some libraries and prevent him from using some commands, for example:

I want to block the open() tool, as user can't use it to create files, and if he tries to use it, this virtual environment should tell him that he can't use this tool.

Comment: The scope of your question is far to broad... please try to narrow down your question to a specific problem....

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.